# How to 'extract' a .vsix file? (i.e. not install)

Tags: vsix, vsixmanifest

Title says it all: How can one 'extract' a .vsix file?

I was following a tutorial and states this as step, but I didn't understand it and it wasn't easily googleable.

Comment: Un-zip or un-install ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Rename the file extension to .zip and voila, just unpack it like a regular zip

Comment: This is also the official method of extracting VSIX package as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/preparing-extensions-for-windows-installer-deployment?view=vs-2022#to-extract-files-from-an-existing-vsix-package) by Microsoft

Answer (score 8):

You can download vsix file 2way. But vsix file downloaded by first site can't extract linux unizp.
you need to download second site.

first one

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/${publisher}/vsextensions/${extensionname}/${version}/vspackage
```

second one

```
https://${publisher}.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/${publisher}/extension/${extensionname}/${version}/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage
```

If CSS Peak

${publisher} = pranaygp

${extensionname} = vscode-css-peek

${version} = 3.0.2

Comment: Although this is not the answer, this is extremely valuable to know when downloading files in Linux (especially in docker containers). :-)